# Creating a table in C++

Tags: java

As a little background, I am working with one of my professors on an LLC resonant converter circuit and the current problem I am dealing with is we need to calculate an "extension" time for the MOSFETs on the board and to do that there is a very complicated equation.  Since we only have about 200 clock cycles to work with, we thought solving this equation for a range of numbers and then putting it into a table would save a lot of time.

So my problem is: I currently have a 20x20 table (Please refer to the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeGNp.png) whose columns correspond to a time (t2) that we will measure (ranging from 1us to 7us (1us, 1.316us, ..., 6.684us, 7us)). The value of the rows is also measured (t3/t2).

So, given these two measured values, I would like to get an output for whatever "Beta" is.

I believe I need to create a header file for this that is indexed by the two known values (t2, t3/t2). I also think I will need to map whatever values are read to an integer between 1 and 20.

I have never done anything like this before, so any pointers are very welcome.

Regards

Edit: My apologies for asking such a broad (and possibly difficult) question. I was wondering if someone can maybe point me in the right direction. I don't expect someone to do this for me, but I wasn't sure where to turn for help on this so I figured StackOverflow would be a good choice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::map`?

Comment: I have looked around and that seems to be my best bet. I just don't have a lot of experience with C++. I've been looking up how to do lookup tables and I think I am on the right track, but the fractional numbers are what is getting me confused now.

Comment: Your real values can be a not exact value of the table I suppose, so how do you choose column/row ? lower, nearest, .... ?

Comment: The way to choose the column/row, I'm thinking, is to maybe increase the size of the table so that there are times from 0.25us to 7us (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, ...,6.75, 7). Then when measuring the value of t2, we multiply it by 4, use the floor function, and then that value would correspond to the column. Accuracy may be an issue, but we can see fine tune it if we must.  Then for the values of t3/t2, they can be multiplied by 2^(10) so that decimals aren't an issue and actual multiplication won't have to occur (just LSLs).... At this point, I'm a little lost now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
static const double table[20 /* for t2*/][20 /*for t3*/] = {
    {1.25, 1.28, ..., 1.54},
    {1.22, 1.25, ..., 1.47},
    ...
};
static const double t2s[20] = {1, 1.31, ..., 7};
static const double betas[20] = {0.6, 0.56, ..., 0.01};

int compute_t2_index(double t2)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(t2s), std::end(t2s), t2);
    // so *(it - 1) <= t2 < *it
    return std::distance(std::begin(t2s), it);
    // you might want to choose the nearest value between *(it - 1) and *it
    // Don't forget to check it with std::begin(t2s) in that case
}

int compute_beta_index(double t2, double t3)
{
    const auto t2_index = compute_t2_index(t2);
    const auto& ratios = table[t2_index];
    const auto ratio = t3 / t2;
    auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(ratios), std::end(ratios), ratio);
    // so *(it - 1) <= ratio < *it
    return std::distance(std::begin(ratios), it);
    // you might want to choose the nearest value between *(it - 1) and *it
    // Don't forget to check it with std::begin(ratios) in that case
}

double compute_beta(double t2, double t3)
{
    return betas[compute_beta_index(t2, t3)];
}
```

Comment: Only having some experience in Java, could I ask you to enlighten me on a couple things? Specifically, what is the: "auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(t2s), std::end(t2s), t2);" line accomplishing, and then the "std::distance(std::begin(t2s), it);" line?

Comment: you may look at [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (find the first element of sorted array where `*it < value` is false (in logarithmic time)) and [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) (compute the distance between 2 iterators, so mainly return the index in the array).

Comment: and then "const auto& ratios = table[t2_index];" is taking the whole column at t2 = value and then we're doing the same thing as the last code... Nice! This makes a lot of sense. You are truly a lifesaver. Thanks. :)